# Angular translation file (ngx-translate) gets loaded twice

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

I have noticed, in the browser's developer tools network tab, that my Angular app translation file is being loaded twice.

What is wrong?
Should this be happening?

[image: network tab]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might happen if the language you use and the default language you set with ng2-translate's `TranslateService`, are the same.

**Wrong:**

```
  constructor(translate: TranslateService) {
    const DEFAULT_LANG = 'en';
    const userLang = translate.getBrowserLang();

    translate.setDefaultLang(DEFAULT_LANG);
    translate.use(userLang);
  }
```

**Proposed solution:**

```
  constructor(translate: TranslateService) {
    const DEFAULT_LANG = 'en';
    const userLang = translate.getBrowserLang();

    if (userLang !== DEFAULT_LANG) {
      translate.setDefaultLang(DEFAULT_LANG);
    }

    translate.use(userLang);
  }
```

This is further discussed in this [ngx-translate issue](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core/issues/397).

Note: you should probably run this logic in a service which watches when the user language is changed.